# Sending an email button - url parameters

Tags: email, custom-button, url

I am trying to create a send email button for a custom sobject, but I am unsure where to find the `rtype` id for the particular object. I tried to follow the documentation but I couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: Read over that question, and use some of the soql snippets inside the developer consoles query editor to get the record type ids for the objects you need.

Comment: Well I just realised that I don t need to get the record type but the rtype code that coresponds for my custom SObject. if I use 003 then it would display a set list of 10 objects, but neither of those are relevant for my case

Comment: That 3 digit code will prefix the id of any custom object you create, and you can get it from there. If you still need more help, either try to [edit] this question and get it reopened, or [ask](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) a new question.